# Removing commits from a branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I am working on a React project that uses `gh-pages` to deploy a website. I accidentally merged my `master` branch with my `gh-pages` branch and brought all of the changes that were on `master` to `gh-pages`. In total, it added 24 commits to my `gh-pages` branch that weren't there before.

I was wondering if there was a way to revert these changes and to take my `gh-pages` branch back to the 6 commits that were there to begin with?

If that is possible, is there a way to remove those 24 extra commits on the `gh-pages` branch from GitHub?

I have looked at resources related to `git reset --hard` and `git rebase` and I am unsure if they would solve my problem. I don't want to destroy the git structure of this project more than it already is.

Comment: Do you plan on merging `master` into `gh-pages` at a later point?

Answer (score 0):

The safest thing to do is to `git revert` the merge commit you made by accident.  By doing a `git revert` it should be noted that you are adding a *new* commit which functionally undoes the merge commit from `master` which you did by accident.  Here is how to do this:

```
# from gh-pages
git log

# find the SHA-a of the merge commit, and then do
git revert -m 1 <merge commit hash>
```

Note that you probably want `-m 1` here, which tells Git to revert back to the first parent, which typically would be your `gh-pages` feature branch.

Note that doing a revert commit here is preferable to trying to cut out the merge commit.  The reason for this is that actually removing the merge commit means *rewriting* history, which can cause trouble for anyone else using your `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: In pushing these changes to GitHub, would it also remove the erroneous commits there as well?

Comment: @arctic Doing `git revert` doesn't actually _remove_ any commits at all.  Instead, it makes a _new_ commit, on top of your branch, which more or less undoes whatever changes were made by the merge commit.  To your exact question: yes, once you push to GitHub, the branch will behave as if you never made the erroneous merge commit with `master`.

Comment: While reverting a faulty merge is the safest thing to do, there are other factors to take into consideration. Is `master` going to be merged into `gh-pages` at a later point in time? If yes, those reverted commits won't be coming back with a new merge.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio Good point, and if the OP has not yet pushed, then maybe a rebase might make more sense.